Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadBanner on channel ironsource_mediation)
flutter doctor
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4037], locale en-IN)
    [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0-rc1)
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
        X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
          Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
          Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
    [√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    [√] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
    [√] Connected device (4 available)
    [√] Network resources

I am using ironsource_mediation: ^2.0.0
When I open the Android app via tapping the notification received from FCM messaging then I get the MissingPluginException exception and not loading the banner or video ads from ironsource. I have tried this in release version of the app.
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 34
multiDexEnabled true

Also ironsoucre init is failing with same exception.
Any idea how to fix this? Could this be an issue with flutter ironsource_mediation plugin ?
